# how to code a command for monitor for this case

Tags: interface, monitor, netlogo

I want to see my min trade_Price on interface with the help of monitor.
my agents. sellers and buyers has 0 trade_Price when they dont have another agent in the same patch. But  I want to see min trade_Price only of the agents who have another agent in one patch.

I code it so :

```
min [trade_Price] of turtles
```

I need some extra code here, have anyone an idea?
best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about `min [trade_Price] of turtles with [trade_Price > 0]` (not tested)

Comment: error (if so what)? or gives a weird answer (if so, why is it weird)? This is definitely the correct code for getting the minimum of some property value after excluding those negative or 0 or missing etc. So I would suggest doing an inspect on some of your turtles to see whether trade_Price values look sensible.

Comment: when I write this code in plot command the name of my plot (which is on the top of plot interface) becomes red. and I didnt become any graphic line in my plot.

Comment: do it as a monitor first (so this text goes into the `reporter' white space) and label it test. Do you have any other plots working? In red means that NetLogo thinks there's an error, and you can hit the pencil next to the plot description (when you edit the plot) to get the error message. I think you have a problem with the plot construction rather than the command.

Comment: yes it works with monitor, but with plot I couldnt set it, thanks for your help :)

Comment: in a plot you need to put a command first, so e.g. `plot count turtles`, not just `count turtles`